# php fopen permission problem

Tags: php, apache-http-server, file-permissions, selinux

I'm learning php, and am having a problem while writing a file upload page.
In the docroot, I have index.php (the page that calls fopen) and a directory called "images", where I wish the temporary file be moved. However, fopen fails with 'permission denied' ( vide /var/log/httpd/error_log ). fopen is called requesting a write.

I scoured the net and found the problem was with permissions on the images dir. I first changed the group owner of the dir to a group different than root and added 'apache' to that group. group has w permission on the dir. (I found out that my Apache was running as user apache with

```
# ps aux| grep httpd
```

This failed.(should have worked, no?)

Again, I chowned the entire images/ dir to be owned by 'apache'. in vain.

And yes, I restarted the server after each of the above changes was made.

thanks,

Yati

PS: My reputation here doesn't allow me to self-answer within 8 hrs, so decided to edit here. With help from Ignacio, the command for changing the SELinux context of the images dir is:

```
# chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t ./images
```

from within the docRoot.

thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is preventing HTTPd from writing into that directory. Use `chcon` to change the file context of `images/` to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`, and if that lets it work then use `semanage` to make it permanent.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot, but httpd_sys_rw_content_t is reported as an invalid context by chcon.

Comment: Which distro are you running?

Comment: fedora 15. any hints?

Comment: That's the correct value for F15. Verify your spelling, and make sure all `selinux-*` packages are up to date.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for pointing me in the right direction. It seems the chcon command will be:

    # chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t images

Thank you

Comment: Don't forget `semanage` to make it permanent.

Comment: I sure won't :) Thanks a ton (wondering how you remember those context names!!)

Comment: `man <service name>_selinux`